# How do you stream an base64 encoded image to a response as a png, using node and express

Tags: node.js, stream, base64, axios

I am using axios to retrieve a base64 png from a third party, and then trying to pipe that to another client as an image.

If I read the full text, I can `res.write(response.data, 'base64');` and the client receives the image I expect.

However if I try and stream it, the client just gets base64 text.

I have tried both `stream.setEncoding('base64');` and using the [Base64Encode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-stream) package.

This is my current code:

```
axios({
    method: 'get',
    timeout: 150000,
    headers,
    url,
    responseType: 'stream'
})
    .then(response => {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' });

        const stream = response.data;
        //stream.setEncoding('base64');
        stream.on('end', () => {
            console.log('ended');
            res.end();
        });
        stream.pipe(new Base64Encode()).pipe(res);
        //stream.pipe(res);
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        logAxiosError(reason);
        res.write('ERROR');
        res.end();
    });
```